# Disposing object in C#

Tags: c#, .net, dispose

I have written the following class:

```
public class CoupleFrames
{
    public CoupleFrames(ColorImageFrame cif, Bitmap df)
    {
        this.colorFrame = cif;
        this.desktopFrame = df;
    }

    public ColorImageFrame colorFrame;
    public Bitmap desktopFrame;
}
```

Now I'm using the following code for disposing the variables.

```
CoupleFrames cf = new CoupleFrames(frame1, frame2);
// some code...
cf.colorFrame.Dispose();
cf.desktopFrame.Dispose();
```

I'm not sure that this is the correct way. Someone can suggest me the correct way for disposing the entire object?

Comment: This depends if you want the type to take ownership of the variables passed in to the constructor; if not, use a using for the variables, otherwise implement IDisposable on the type and have it manage the resources.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

> I'm not sure that this is the correct way. Someone can suggest me the correct way for disposing the entire object?

Sure - you should make `CoupleFrames` implement `IDisposable`, and *its* `Dispose` method should dispose of the objects it "owns". For example:

```
public sealed class CoupleFrames : IDisposable
{
    private readonly ColorImageFrame colorFrame;
    private readonly Bitmap desktopFrame;

    public CoupleFrames(ColorImageFrame cif, Bitmap df)
    {
        // TODO: Argument validation, unless it's valid for these parameters
        // to be null, in which case the Dispose method would need to be careful.
        this.colorFrame = cif;
        this.desktopFrame = df;
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        colorFrame.Dispose();
        desktopFrame.Dispose();
    }
}
```

A few points to note:

- You should make sure it's clear that the `CoupleFrame` really "owns" these constituent objects. Disposal relies on a clear ownership model
- If `CoupleFrame` *isn't* sealed (and can't be) you may need to go into a more complicated pattern with virtual methods and finalizers. It can get very complicated, and you should read the [advice given here by Joe Duffy et al](http://joeduffyblog.com/2005/04/08/dg-update-dispose-finalization-and-resource-management/). If your class is sealed, a lot of that complexity goes away
- Public fields are generally a bad idea (in terms of encapsulation), which is why I've made them private here. I've also made them readonly, as if they can be changed later you need to think about whether changing them should dispose of the previously-referenced object etc.
- By making `CoupleFrame` implement `IDisposable`, you're basically telling all clients that they should dispose of any instance they own. If you're not happy with imposing that burden, you need to rethink the design a bit.

Comment: As `CoupleFrames` doesn't instantiate those 2 private members, we should check for NRE in the dispose method.

Comment: @ken2k: I'd actually put non-nullity validation in the constructor. Will edit to indicate that.

Comment: @ken2k So, I need also to test if the members are null?

Comment: @Joseph82: You need to test *somewhere* - is it valid for `null` values to be passed into the constructor? If not, throw an exception there. If it is, check before you try to dispose.

Answer (score 3):

I would implement the [Dispose pattern](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b1yfkh5e%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

```
public class CoupleFrames : IDisposable
{
    public CoupleFrames(ColorImageFrame cif, Bitmap df)
    {
        this.colorFrame = cif;
        this.desktopFrame = df;
    }

    public ColorImageFrame colorFrame;
    public Bitmap desktopFrame;

    private bool disposed;

    public void Dispose()
    {
        Dispose(true);
        GC.SupressFinalize(this); 
    }

    protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (disposed)
        {
            return;
        }
        if (disposing)
        {
            colorFrame.Dispose();
            desktopFrame.Dispose();
        }
        disposed = true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use the `IDisposable` interface.

```
public class CoupleFrames : IDisposable
{
    ....

    public void Dispose()
    {
        // Your disposing code here
    }

    ~CoupleFrames()
    {
        Dispose();
    }
}
```

You can use the destructor to call the Dispose method since the object can sometimes be deleted by the GC.

Answer (score -3):

Make CoupleFrames Implement the Idisposable Interface.

```
public class CoupleFrames : IDisposable
{
    public CoupleFrames(ColorImageFrame cif, Bitmap df)
    {
        this.colorFrame = cif;
        this.desktopFrame = df;
    }

    public ColorImageFrame colorFrame;
    public Bitmap desktopFrame;

    public void Dispose()
    {
        cf.colorFrame.Dispose();
        cf.desktopFrame.Dispose();
    }
```